# Java constructor usage in different classes

Tags: java, class, constructor, uri

I'm using a constructor to init a object in a different class than the constructor itself. The constructor gets a string and returns an object instance. But how do I get the string from the class creating the object to the class where the constructor is defined?
My project is like this:

The class with the constructor:

```
public class UriParserImplementation implements UriParser {

@Override
public Uri parse() {    
    return null;
}
public UriParserImplementation(String uri) {
}
}
```

This is the class using the constructor with a string to create an object instance:

```
public final class UriParserFactory {
    public static UriParser create(String uri) {
        UriParser parser = new UriParserImplementation(uri);
        return parser;
    }
}
```

And I wanted to use the string used by UriParserFactory in UriParserImplementation but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Why not use a field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how do I get the string from the class creating the object to the class where the constructor is defined?

The component needs to save the String in a field, and you need to call the method which retrieves the String.  There is no magic about this, it's something you have to code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to pass a `uri` string to `UriParserImplementation`'s constructor and be able to access it in `UriParserImplementation` later, after an instance has been created?

If that is the case, you need to add an attribute/field to the `UriParserImplementation` class and initialize it in the constructor:

```
public class UriParserImplementation implements UriParser {
    String originalUri;

    public UriParserImplementation(String uri) {
        originalUri = uri;
    }

    public parse() {
        // you can access originalUri here
    }
```